How to center the items vertically in bottom tab-bar navigation after increasing it's height in react native?
I have created this bottom tab navigation using the react native expo router.
I needed to increase the height of the tab-bar, so I did but now I am wondering how I can center the items vertically in react native?
This is what my navigation tabs look like
enter image description here
I have tried playing around with tabBarItemStyle, tabBarStyle and tabBarLabelStyle but none of them gave me the result and nowhere I found the solution. So please help.
Here is how the _layout of the tab group looks like:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router'
import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";


import MaterialCommunityIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import MaterialIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { AntDesign, Entypo, FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function MainTabsLayout() {
    return (
        <Tabs
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                    height: 100
                },
                tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.dark.green,
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.dark.gray,

                tabBarItemStyle: {
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                },
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: "700",
                    marginTop: -2,
                },

            }}>
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='index'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => <MaterialIcons name="games" size={22} color={focused ? Colors.dark.green : color} />,
                    tabBarLabel: "Matches",
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                    },

                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='news'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => <Entypo name="news" size={20} color={focused ? Colors.dark.green : color} />,
                    tabBarLabel: "News",
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                    }
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='leagues'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => <AntDesign name="Trophy" size={20} color={focused ? Colors.dark.green : color} />,
                    tabBarLabel: "Leagues",
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                    }
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='following'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => focused ? <AntDesign name="star" size={20} color={Colors.dark.green} /> : <FontAwesome5 name="star" size={18} color={focused ? Colors.dark.green : color} />,
                    tabBarLabel: "Following",
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                    }
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name='more'
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => <Entypo name="menu" size={20} color={focused ? Colors.dark.green : color} />,
                    tabBarLabel: "More",
                    tabBarLabelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "700",
                    }
                }}
            />
        </Tabs>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})


Here's the updated code with vertical centering for the tab bar:

// ... existing code ...
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                height: 100,
                paddingVertical: 0,
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.dark.green,
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.dark.gray,
            tabBarItemStyle: {
                height: '100%',
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0,
            },
            tabBarIconStyle: {
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                marginBottom: 0,
            },
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: "700",
                marginTop: 0,
                paddingBottom: 15, // Label'ı aşağıya itmek için
            },
        }}


// ... existing code ...


Added paddingVertical: 0 to tabBarStyle
Set tabBarItemStyle to full height with no padding/margins
Added tabBarIconStyle with flex and centering properties
Adjusted tabBarLabelStyle with marginTop: 0 and added paddingBottom

These changes will center the icons and labels vertically within the tab bar while maintaining proper spacing.
